# Git Delete branch from my FORK

Tags: git

What is the command used to delete the branch just from my fork (I think it is called 'locally').
I used `git branch -d local_branch` I am seeing:

```
error: Cannot delete the branch 'local_branch' which you are currently on.
```

What is the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Before you can delete the branch, you should checkout to some other branch. Even then, `git branch -d` will refuse to delete the branch if commit that branch is pointing to will become unreachable from some other branch.

If you merge your working branch into master branch, it will make those commits still reachable (by merge commits), and `git branch -d` should delete your working branch without complaints.

If you really, positively want to nuke that branch, you can use `git branch -D` - but it may lead to loss of your work.

Comment: I did a commit & push to my fork, but did not merge to the branch on master yet, as these changes are no longer needed, I want to clean the branch on my fork by deleting it on my fork locally and getting it again from master, it did throw me the same error when I switched to another branch.

Comment: If you delete branch locally with `-D`, you may lose your work. If you *have* pushed it, you must have pushed it to some non-master branch (probably named after your local one). When you pull this branch again from remote, you will get those commits back again - seems rather pointless exercise.